# Merging 2 tables

Tags: mysql

I have 2 tables `t1` and `t2`:

`t1`

```
Names    Courses

James      A
James      B
Tom        Z
```

`t2`

```
Names    Courses

James      A
Tom        Y
Tom        Z
```

I want to merge those 2 tables to a new table that looks like this

```
Names    Courses

James      A
James      B
Tom        Y
Tom        Z
```

Really appreciate if someone can help me with this.

Answer (score 3):

You need next query:

```
SELECT `Names`, `Courses` FROM t1
UNION DISTINCT
SELECT `Names`, `Courses` FROM t2
```

As stated in the [documentation](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.5/en/union.html) `DISTINCT` keyword has no effect and you can omit it. But using it can increase readability of your code.

Comment: Personally, I prefer `UNION` instead of `UNION DISTINCT`, because meaning is the same but first form is SQL 92 compatible

Comment: I agree you answer should be approved. I'm not question owner :). Anyway, according to mysql doc DISTINCT has no effect: https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/union.html